# Sending data to PHP file with pure JS (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know how to use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'send-data-to.php',
  data: {data:"data"}
})
```

but how do I send data accessible via `$_POST` with pure JS? The reason I'm asking this is because I followed a YouTube tutorial for an `Ajax file upload` but I also want to send more data along with it (and I don't know how to do it with pure JS).

Here's the main part of it.

JS

```
function uploadFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = document.getElementById('upload-btn').files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1",file);
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress",progressHandler,false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load",completeHandler,false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error",errorHandler,false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort",abortHandler,false);
    ajax.open("POST","upload_file.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="uploadFile(event);">
    <input class="next-btn" type="submit" value="Upload!">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="upload-btn" onchange="showImage(this);">
</form>
```

The data I want to send would be like this using using jQuery:

`data: {var1:var1,var2:var2,var3:var3}` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

From [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Ah, I see. I can just keep appending it on to the `formdata` variable.

Comment: Okay, though the real answer was the second one for me (in that link, not the one you pasted) :D

Comment: @frosty anyway this act would be appreciated :)